# Zend - Conditional Based on Controller Action - Possible?

Tags: zend-framework

From a header.php layout we can give instructions based on a given controller by doing:

`$this->controller === "mycontrollerhere";`

Can we do more or less the same but with a specific controller Action ?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're after but the front controller request object contains the names of the requested module, controller and action.